# Is this triangulation consistent with Sperner's Lemma?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, definition, triangulation

[image]
[image]

Since any two triangles which intersect have an edge or a vertex in common, the triangulation is simplicial.

However, I am concerned about triangle $A$. Is every sub-triangle supposed to have a vertex in common with the main outer triangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangle immediately to the left of triangle $A$ (lets call it $X$) and the large triangle to its right (the one that includes side $RB$) intersect, but have no common vertex or side. So this is not a simplical subdivision. The same could be said for triangle $X$ and the triangle directly below it (the one without the label $A$ in its interior) as well.

Comment: The bottom right vertex of $A$ is in common with the vertex opposite the side $RB$. No?

Comment: My mistake. I was looking at the triangle next to $A$. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: Ah ok, I see why it is not simplicial. But in general, are we allowed to have sub-triangles in the middle with no vertex in common with the sides of the main outer triangle?

Comment: Well if you remove triangle $X$, what remains is simplical and there exists a triangle with all its vertices distinct from $R,G,$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a simplicial triangulation.

But yes, triangles are allowed to have nothing on the boundary of the original triangle (though they are of course inside that triangle). Note by the way that only five triangles in the above triangulation have a *vertex in common* with the original triangle, which is not the same as having a vertex on the boundary of that triangle. But in any case there is no requirement of this kind; in a typical simplicial triangulation, most triangles will actually be entirely in the interior of the original triangle.